# Laravel use DB::table for custom fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i want to use custom fields such as `COUNT` and etc into `DB::table()`. this below code is not correct

For Example:

```
$query =  DB::table('webInformation')
->select('id', 'count( DISTINCT ipAddress )')
->where('webLink = 1 ')->first();
```

or

```
$query =  DB::select('select * , count( DISTINCT ipAddress ) , count( ipAddress )
          from webInformation where webLink = ?', array(1))->first();
```

i have two problem

1. i cant use first()
2. i can not use count

Comment: Add group by ipAddress if you count on this column

Answer (score 1):

Use DB::raw to avoid Laravel escaping the query.

```
$query =  DB::table('webInformation')
->select('id', DB::raw('count( DISTINCT ipAddress ) as diffCount'))
->where('webLink',=,'1 ')->first();
```

Count result will be available in `diffCount` key.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this so you can access the key properly.

```
$q = DB::table('webInformation')
       ->select('id', 'ipAddress', DB::raw("count(ipAddress) AS total"))
       ->where('webLink',=,'1 ')
       ->groupBy('ipAddress')
       ->get();
```

Now you can access it via the key `count` instead of a key like `count(ipAddress)`.